# How do I get the list of copied files with Wildcard paths in azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to send the notification email which includes all file names being copied in ADF. I use Wildcard paths for Source but I could not find any copied file name in Copy Activity output. Is there any way I can find the list of all copied files ?

Any pointers shall be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is your target location of copy activity here?

Comment: target location of copy activity is sftp

Comment: I have given one approach. Try and let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Copy activity won't give the copied file names in its output but it will give the count of copied files**. To achieve your requirement, follow the below approach.

First add a Get meta data activity before your copy activity. For this, the dataset path should be till the folder level.

[image]

In the activity, **give the **Start time** and **End time** as same as copy activity `Start time` and `End time` expression**. For sample, I have given `@adddays(utcnow(),-2)` in the Start Time.

[image]

You can see the `filesWritten` in the copy activity output.

[image]

After copy activity, check this **filesWritten** and the above child items array length in an if activity with below expression.

```
@equals(activity('Copy data1').output.filesWritten, length(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems))
```

[image]

Inside **True activities** of if, add your web activity to send **Success mail** and add the Get meta data activity child items array in the body like below.

```
{
"files_list": @{activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems}
}
```

[image]

You can add another web activity for the **Failure mail** in the False activities of if.

Comment: I have a log file that contains the pair of file name and email that needs to be notified when file is copied. Is there anyway I can pick up the email and add it to web activity ?

Comment: Yes, use lookup on that file and pass the lookup output array in the body of the web activity. In the logic app, make a loop with that array, and add send email action in each iteration. On success, log file output array will be passed to logic app and logic app will iterate through every file and sends the mail in each iteration.